# Using scala variable in executing awk system command in scala

Tags: regex, scala, process, awk

I have a command cat filename | awk 'match($0,/regext_patt/,a) {print a[1] ;exit;}'
I want to run this command using scala sys.process. Here "filename" and "regex_patt" will be coming from scala defined variables.So far I am able to manage this :

```
val extract = (s"cat $file" #| Process(Seq("awk", "match($0,/.+Country=([^;]*);.+/,a) {print a[1] ;exit(0);}"))).!!
```

Issue here is with the regular expression pattern , which is hard-coded and I am not able to get around with how to use scala variable inside the Seq process builder.

I tried this but its giving errors :

```
val reg:String = ".+Country=([^;]*);.+"
val extract= (s"cat $file" #| Process(Seq("awk", "match($0,/",reg,"/,a) {print a[1] ;exit(0);}"))).!
```

and the error here is :

```
awk: match($0,/
awk:           ^ unexpected newline or end of string
awk: cmd. line:1: match($0,/
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

please help with what key thing I am missing here to sort this out . thanks in advance

Comment: Why not `"match($0,/"+reg+"/,a) {print a[1] ;exit(0);}"`?

Comment: OH !!! Tricky and simple .. this didn't occur to me .. Thanks it works wonderfully well !!

Comment: @red1ynx Please post that as an answer so we know this question doesn't remain unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple string concatenation:
`"match($0,/" + reg + "/,a) {print a[1] ;exit(0);}"`